# How to restrict stored procedure to execute query which is set to deny for update / delete operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Currently, I have denied some operation on system object by doing:

```
DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON OBJECT::sph_syslog TO SQLEditorSpecificUser;
```

And it is not allowing me to do any direct operation on an object. Then I have given the following permission to execute and alter the stored procedure.

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::dbo TO SQLEditorSpecificUser;
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO SQLEditorSpecificUser;
```

Now, when I try to execute the stored procedure with following details:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AshishTest]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE sph_syslog 
    SET duration = 8285  
    WHERE id = 1372042 
END
```

On executing this stored procedure (`Execute AshishTest`), it is updating the `syslog` table.

I do not want to update or delete syslog directly or indirectly. How I can achieve that?

Comment: That's the whole idea behind permission chaining. If you don't want that user to be able to affect the table `sph_syslog` via `AshishTest`, then they should not have permission to `EXECUTE` it.

Comment: Actually, I want this particular object to restrict only. Rest of all the data table and procedure should be able to run.

Comment: If `sph_syslog` is actually in the `dbo` schema, the last thing you should do is grant `CONTROL` and `ALTER`, as this allows the user to simply drop the table wholesale, never mind what they can do through stored procedures. You can't secure individual objects if you've granted broad permissions on the higher levels; any time you feel the need to resort to an explicit `DENY` it usually indicates a problem with your setup that should be solved by rearranging things altogether.

Comment: Consider creating the `sph_syslog` table in a schema other than `dbo` owned by a different user and with no permissions. This will break the ownership chain and only users with an explicit grant or membership in a privileged role can access the table.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is actually by design, and is how permission chaining works; if you give someone permission to (for example) `EXECUTE` a procedure and that procedure `UPDATE`s a table that has the *same* owner then permission is still granted. This allows administrators to `DENY` `USER`s access to a `TABLE` but they still have permission to use a `VIEW` (which might, for example, expose fewer columns), or not allow a `USER` to `UPDATE` a table directly but can through a `PROCEDURE` (as it has additional workflow defined in it).

The method [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) recommends in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731801/how-to-restrict-stored-procedure-to-execute-query-which-is-set-to-deny-for-updat?noredirect=1#comment133597639_75731801) is probably the "best" way; change the schema the object is on and ensure that schema is owned by a different `USER` (or not `dbo`).

An alternative method, if you "can't" do this (perhaps moving the object's schema will be a breaking change) would be to use a deferred statement by using `sys.sp_executesql`; this will also break the ownership chain.

I demonstrate both in the below, but suggest that the schema solution is the *better* option:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO


CREATE USER SomeUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER AnotherUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int,
                            SomeVal varchar(10));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID,
                           SomeVal)
VALUES(1,'abc'),(2,'def');
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @ID int, @SomeVal varchar(10) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
    SET SomeVal = @SomeVal
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END
GO

DENY INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.SomeTable TO SomeUser;

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.SomeProc TO SomeUser;
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.SomeProc TO AnotherUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc 1, 'xyz'; --Works
GO
REVERT;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.SomeProc @ID int, @SomeVal varchar(10) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET SomeVal = @SomeVal WHERE ID = @ID;', N'@ID int, @SomeVal varchar(10)', @ID, @SomeVal;

END
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc 2, 'abc'; --Fails
GO

REVERT;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA SomeSchema AUTHORIZATION AnotherUser; --Has a different owner
GO
ALTER SCHEMA SomeSchema TRANSFER dbo.SomeTable;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.SomeProc @ID int, @SomeVal varchar(10) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE SomeSchema.SomeTable
    SET SomeVal = @SomeVal
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc 2, 'abc'; --Fails
GO

REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeSchema.SomeTable;
GO
EXECUTE AS USER = 'AnotherUser';
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc 2, 'abc'; --Works, as they own the schema
GO

REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeSchema.SomeTable;

GO

DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc;
DROP TABLE SomeSchema.SomeTable;
DROP SCHEMA SomeSchema;
DROP USER SomeUser;
DROP USER AnotherUser;
```